# What and how is this legal problem in java inheritence?

Tags: java, inheritance

The following program leads to an error message of the type "constructor A () not found in class A":

```
class A {
   A (int i) {}
} 
class B extends A {}
```

If a constructor as defined below is in class B, however propose a legal program. Why?

```
class B extends A {
  B (int i) {
      super (i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't define a constructor, you get a default 0-ary constructor which does nothing except call the super constructor. So your first `B` class looks like

```
class B extends A {
  B() {
    super();
  }
}
```

And there's no `A()` for the `super` call to resolve to, hence the error. For this reason, the only time you can omit a constructor in a child class is if the parent can be default constructed.

Comment: I didn't find any error when I Did the same in my compiler.

Comment: super calls the constructor of the parent class with the same signature right? So I couldn't get whats the problem here.

Comment: is the Error because he defined some object like `A obj = new A();`